# Showing values in second dropdown list corresponding to first dropdown list selected item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

Form contains two dropdown lists created using code below.
Both dropdown list elements have property Alusdok.
If item in first dropdown is selected, second dropdown should show only those items whose Alusdok
properties have same aluses as in first dropdown selected item Alusdok property.

Both list are small, contain 1-30 elements. Which is best UI for this?
How to implement this, can some jQuery magic applied or other idea ?

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("_Report", Model.Reports, new { size = 10 })%>
<%= Html.DropDownList("_Paring", Model.Parings, new { size = 10 })%>


viewmodel:

    public class ReportViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
public List<SelectListItem> Reports { get; set; }
public string _Report { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> Parings { get; set; }
public string _Paring { get; set; }

public ReportViewModel() {
...
            Reports = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (ReportElem r in GetReportList())
                Reports.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = r.Nimetus, Value = r.Alusdok + r.Jrk.ToString() });

            Parings = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (ParingElem p in GetParings())
                Parings.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= p.DisplayName, Value= p.Id.ToString() });
        }
    }


public class ReportElem {
  public string Nimetus,Alusdok;
  public int Jrk;
  }

public class ParingElem {
  public string DisplayName, Alusdok;
  public int Id;
  }
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 , jQuery, jQueryUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an action that accepts a `ReportElem.Alusdok` value and returns a JSON list of `ParingElem` objects.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetParingElems(string parentAlusdok)
{
    // construct a list formatted like this from your data layer, etc
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>() {
        new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Alusdok 1" },
        new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Alusdok 2" },
        new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Alusdok 3" }
    };

    return Json(list);
}
```

Then, you could use jQuery to call this action and populate your second dropdown list. It looks like your dropdowns have id's: `_Report` and `_Paring`, so I assume that below.

```
$('#_Report').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetParingElems',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { parentAlusdok: $('#_Report').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { // this is the returned JSON list
            $('#_Paring').remove();
            // iterate over data
            // i and optionData are arbitrary variable names
            $.each(data, function (i, optionData) {
                $('#_Paring').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(optionData.Value).html(optionData.Text)
                );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Keep in mind you might need to modify your routing (probably in global.asax) to accept requests of the form `/ControllerName/GetParingElems/{parentAlusdok}`. You may also need to tweak the `url` argument of the `$.ajax` call if your action resides in another controller, etc.

Comment: thank you. I tried but got error in `$('#_Paring').clear()` line about missing method clear(). I searched jQuery docs and havent found such method. I commented out this line but after that got error in next line that data is not defined. How to fix ? Also, how to select item in first dropdown after it is loaded and how to select first item in second dropdown after it is populatated?

Comment: @Andrus Sorry about that--I think the function is called `.remove()`, and you can find the details at http://api.jquery.com/remove/. But, just a simple call to `.remove()` with no arguments should clear it out on each successive request so you don't have a duplicate-append problem.

Comment: thank you. After replacing clear to remove exception occurs at next line `$.each(data, function (i, optionData) {`  : data is not defined. How to fix this? Also if page is initially shown, second dropdown is empty. How to fill second dropdown also is page is initially displayed? Viewmodel _Report property contains _Report dropdown defsult property.

Comment: @Andrus I suppose this is what I get from copying and pasting code, but it's just a misnamed variable. I edited a couple other lines to clean it up.

Comment: thank you. I verified that optionData.Value and optionData.Text have values. However `$('#_Paring').append(
$('<option></option>').val(optionData.Value).html(optionData.Text));` does not show any data in second dropdown. How to show data in second dropdown ?

Comment: maybe remove() removes select element. In this case adding option does not work

Comment: @Andrus I just tested with `.empty()` and it worked as expected. Sorry for the runaround as far as jQuery methods. You should take some time to look through the jQuery API. There are a lot of problems to be solved with simple methods.